# Student loan forgiveness - how does the refund work?

Tags: united-states, student-loan

Under Biden's new student loan forgiveness plan, I would have qualified for $10,000 of debt relief. However, taking advantage of the last two years of pandemic related forbearance, I recently paid off my loans in full.

According to the [announcement](https://studentaid.gov/announcements-events/covid-19/payment-pause-zero-interest) for the relief, you can receive a refund for any payments made during the pause. What the announcement doesn't make clear is how that refund interacts with the forgiveness plan.

If I get a refund for the full forgiveness amount ($10,000), is that considered "free money" as it would have been forgiven anyway, or does my loan balance increase correspondingly? If it does increase, can I still go through the forgiveness procedure to wipe that balance out, or would I have to pay back the new balance normally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine eligibility and receive Federal Student Loan forgiveness?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152317/how-do-i-determine-eligibility-and-receive-federal-student-loan-forgiveness)

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. That question asks about eligibility under a situation where the borrower(s) still have outstanding debt. In my case, I don't have reason to expect to be ineligible, and I don't have outstanding debt (although it was all paid off during the forbearance period, which is a crucial distinction).

Comment: My point is that the answer will be the same: no-one knows because rules haven't been written yet. It's just an announcement.

Comment: The answer may be the same right now, but the situations are clearly different. When the implementation becomes known, I can't imagine both questions will have the same answer.